# How to make bootstrap 4 dismissible alert close permanently

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, alert, dismissible

I have a MediaWiki site, and literally all I want to do is make a bootstrap 4 alert visible for any new visitors on certain pages, but stay permanently gone when it is dismissed. The alert would be transcluded to multiple pages, but if dismissed should no longer appear on any of them. I've found lots of answers for how to do this, but I don't understand javascript at all so I can't figure out how to use them, and copy/pasting the solutions isn't working. The alert displays and can be closed, but it's visible again if the page is refreshed/revisited. This is my very basic code:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 10px; color: black; background: white; padding: 10px 25px 10px 15px; max-width: 600px;" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible"><span style="font-size: 1em; color: white; background: blue; border-radius: 20px; padding: 8px;" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">Dismiss</span>Testing text.</div>
```

I've tried reversing this issue because I want it to stay closed: [My Bootstrap alert will not display after being closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20494887/my-bootstrap-alert-will-not-display-after-being-closed)

I've tried copying this code but it didn't work with my alert: [Using Bootstrap, have alert box remember close action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408244/using-bootstrap-have-alert-box-remember-close-action)

I've also tried copying the both cookie and local storage versions of this question's answer and it didn't work with my alert: [Bootstrap 4 alert permanently closed with a cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63577973/bootstrap-4-alert-permanently-closed-with-a-cookie)

Every single code I tried did not keep the alert from re-appearing every time after a refresh or a page revisit.

Answer (score 0):

A dismissible alert its only for allow to close it, if you need display an alert and remember the choice, you need cookies or local storage and some javascript interaction like:

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wellcome-message"
        style="display: none; border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 10px; color: black; background: white; padding: 10px 25px 10px 15px; max-width: 600px;"
        class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible"><span
            style="font-size: 1em; color: white; background: blue; border-radius: 20px; padding: 8px;" class="close"
            data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">Dismiss</span>Testing text.</div>
    <script>
        function IsValidJsonString(Input) {
            try {
                JSON.parse(Input);
            } catch (ex) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        var Base64 = {
            _keyStr: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",
            encode: function (input) {
                var output = "";
                var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
                var i = 0;
                input = Base64._utf8_encode(input);
                while (i < input.length) {
                    chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
                    chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
                    chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
                    enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
                    enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
                    enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
                    enc4 = chr3 & 63;
                    if (isNaN(chr2)) {
                        enc3 = enc4 = 64;
                    } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
                        enc4 = 64;
                    }
                    output = output +
                        this._keyStr.charAt(enc1) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
                        this._keyStr.charAt(enc3) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc4);
                }
                return output;
            },
            decode: function (input) {
                var output = "";
                var chr1, chr2, chr3;
                var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
                var i = 0;
                input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");
                while (i < input.length) {
                    enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
                    enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
                    enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
                    enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
                    chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
                    chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
                    chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;
                    output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);
                    if (enc3 != 64) {
                        output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
                    }
                    if (enc4 != 64) {
                        output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
                    }
                }
                output = Base64._utf8_decode(output);
                return output;
            },
            _utf8_encode: function (string) {
                string = string.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
                var utftext = "";
                for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {
                    var c = string.charCodeAt(n);
                    if (c < 128) {
                        utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
                    } else if ((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
                        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
                        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
                    } else {
                        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
                        utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
                        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
                    }
                }
                return utftext;
            },
            _utf8_decode: function (utftext) {
                var string = "";
                var i = 0;
                var c = c1 = c2 = 0;
                while (i < utftext.length) {
                    c = utftext.charCodeAt(i);
                    if (c < 128) {
                        string += String.fromCharCode(c);
                        i++;
                    } else if ((c > 191) && (c < 224)) {
                        c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 1);
                        string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63));
                        i += 2;
                    } else {
                        c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 1);
                        c3 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 2);
                        string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63));
                        i += 3;
                    }
                }
                return string;
            }
        };
        setLocalStorage = function (c_name, value, exdays) {
            if (value === null || value === undefined) {
                window.localStorage.removeItem(c_name);
                window.localStorage.removeItem(c_name + "_expire");
            } else {
                window.localStorage.setItem(c_name, Base64.encode(JSON.stringify(value)));
                var exdate = new Date();
                exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + ($.isNumeric(exdays) ? exdays : 0));
                window.localStorage.setItem(c_name + "_expire", Base64.encode(exdate.toUTCString()));
            }
        };
        getLocalStorage = function (c_name) {
            var _time = window.localStorage.getItem(c_name + "_expire")
            var _value = window.localStorage.getItem(c_name);
            try {
                if (_time !== null && _time !== undefined) {
                    if (Date.parse(Base64.decode(_time)) <= new Date()) {
                        window.localStorage.removeItem(c_name + "_expire");
                        window.localStorage.removeItem(c_name);
                        return null;
                    } else {
                        if (IsValidJsonString(Base64.decode(_value)))
                            return JSON.parse(Base64.decode(_value));
                    }
                }
            } catch (ex) {
                return null;
            }
            return null;
        };
        $(function () {
            if (!getLocalStorage("WellcomeMessage"))
                $("#wellcome-message").show();
            $("#wellcome-message span.close").click(function () {
                setLocalStorage("WellcomeMessage", true, 999999);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Tested ;)

Comment: I don't know if my site being a wiki has anything to do with it, but this didn't work either. I can't edit anything in the head tag because I don't have acces to it, so I tried just leaving that part out, and then adding the javascript to my wiki's MediaWiki:Common.js page.

Now the alert doesn't show up at all unless I remove the "display: none;" style, but when I do so the alert still doesn't stay dismissed.